# Proper and most efficient way to iterate through an NSMutableSet?

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, cocos2d-iphone

Some Context: In my destructible terrain library for Cocos2D, one of the features is collapsable terrain. In order to collapse efficiently, I store the columns whose pixels have been altered in a NSMutableSet which contains NSNumbers which contain integers. I am using this data structure because I don't want to iterate over duplicate columns.

My first instinct for how to loop through the NSMutableSet was to use a 'for in' loop.

```
for (NSNumber * col in [alteredColumns allObjects]) { // Works 
// for (NSNumber * col in alteredColumns) { // Crashes
    int x = col.intValue;
    bool shouldShift = false;
    bool alphaFound = false;
    for (int y = (size_.height -1); y >= 0; y--) {
        if (!shouldShift) {
            if ([self pixelAt:ccp(x,y)].a == 0) {
                // Need to shift all pixels above one down
                alphaFound = true;
            } else if (alphaFound) {
                didCollapse = shouldShift = true;
                // Ensure the top pixel is alpha'ed out if a collapse will occur
                [self setPixelAt:ccp(x,0) rgba:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 0)];
                [self setPixelAt:ccp(x,(y+1)) rgba:[self pixelAt:ccp(x,y)]];
            } // end inner if
        } else {
            // Need to shift pixels down one
            [self setPixelAt:ccp(x,(y+1)) rgba:[self pixelAt:ccp(x,y)]];
        } // end if
    } // end inner for
    // Remove column from cache if no pixels collapsed
    if (!shouldShift) [alteredColumns removeObject:col];
} // end outer for
```

However, this led to bad results. The program would crash with a Bad Access Memory error. If I alter the for loop to use [alteredColumns allObjects], then everything works just fine. So Questions... Can a 'for in' loop not be used on an unordered collection such as a NSMutableSet? If I must use a method such as allObjects, is this efficient?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!shouldShift) [alteredColumns removeObject:col]; //1
```

In this line you modify `alteredColumns`. Modifying collections while enumerating is a bad, bad thing. If you are lucky, you'll get BAD_ACCESS, at the worst you won't even notice that something went wrong till you get totally unexpected behaviour.

```
for (NSNumber * col in [alteredColumns allObjects]) //2
```

Here you create an NSArray (`[NSSet allObjects]` returns an NSArray), and enumerate this array. When you modify `alteredColumns` in line //1, enumerated array is not mutated.

```
for (NSNumber * col in alteredColumns) { //3
```

And with this line you are enumerating alteredColumns, which *is* modified in line //1.

Comment: You are correct indeed. It is easy to overlook the little things sometimes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, BOOL *stop))block
```